# Custom dynamic paging using stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, paging

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetPageWiseData]
(
    @tableName sysname,
    @orderColumn nvarchar(100),
    @PageIndex INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @RecordCount varchar(10) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @query varchar(2000),
        @minimumIndex varchar(5),
        @maximumIndex varchar(5)

SET @minimumIndex=convert(varchar,(@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
SET @maximumIndex=convert(varchar,@PageIndex * @PageSize)

SET @query='SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @orderColumn + ' ASC)AS RowNumber,* INTO #Results FROM ' + @tableName + ';
            SELECT ' + @RecordCount + '=COUNT(*) FROM #Results;
            SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ' + @minimumIndex + ' AND ' + @maximumIndex + ';
            DROP TABLE #Results'
Exec (@query)   
END
```

Here is the problem is when the procedure is executed, output parameter `@RecordCount` shows NULL value.

WHY?

Please explain.
Thanks

Comment: You should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. That prefix has been reserved by Microsoft for its own future use. Use anything else - just not `sp_` ...

Comment: Why are you returnign only row numbers from the code? And using dynamic SQL is the wrong approach in this case. Use one procedure per table

Comment: get the idea from here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be like this:

```
SET @query='SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @orderColumn + ' ASC)AS RowNumber,* INTO #Results FROM ' + @tableName + ';
        SELECT  @RecordCount =COUNT(*) FROM #Results;
        SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ' + @minimumIndex + ' AND ' + @maximumIndex + ';
        DROP TABLE #Results';
```

But here system will ask you to declare the variable, @RecordCount

so you can do it like this by returning 2 datasets from the query;

```
SET @query='DECLARE @RecordCount varchar(10); SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @orderColumn + ' ASC)AS RowNumber,* INTO #Results FROM ' + @tableName + ';
        SELECT  @RecordCount =COUNT(*) FROM #Results;
        SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ' + @minimumIndex + ' AND ' + @maximumIndex + ';
        SELECT @RecordCount AS TOTALRECORDS;
        DROP TABLE #Results';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant use it on this way. It's like concatanation not a value assign method. I think you should handle it in two steps, something like this:

```
SET @query='SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @orderColumn + ' ASC)AS RowNumber,* INTO #Results FROM ' + @tableName + ';'

Exec (@query)

SELECT @RecordCount =COUNT(*) FROM #Results

SET @query='SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ' + @minimumIndex + ' AND ' + @maximumIndex + ';
DROP TABLE #Results'

Exec (@query)
```

Comment: I think in this case SQL will say that #Results is not defined, as it is in the scope of first execution of @query.